# Firebase data loads slower than UITableView

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview

I am able to successfully retrieve data from my Firebase database however it does not load fast enough to be recognized by some of the functions used by UITableView.

Upon the TableView calling numberOfRowsInSection, I am getting an error that says "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" because I am returning the number of items in an array being populated with Firebase data; by the time this function is called, there is no data in the array yet.

If I print the data in the array anywhere else, it shows.

I have tried placing the code to retrieve data from Firebase in viewDidAppear() as well as viewWillAppear().

```
//
//  PostsViewController.swift
//  cheerup-ios
//
//  Created by Diamonique Danner on 12/26/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Danner Opp., LLC. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase

var postDictionary : NSDictionary!
var currentPost : String!
var postData : [Any]!

@IBOutlet var postsTable: UITableView!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let dbRef = Database.database().reference()
    dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let posts = value!["posts"] as? NSDictionary
        self.postDictionary = posts!

        for post in posts! {
            self.postData.append(post)
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

   // print(self.postData)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    postsTable.dataSource = self
    postsTable.delegate = self  
}

@IBAction func logOut(_ sender: Any) {
    let firebase = Auth.auth()
    do {
        try firebase.signOut()
    } catch let signOutError as NSError {
        print(signOutError)
    }
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
    self.present(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
 return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

print(self.postData)
    return self.postData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = self.postsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
//  cell.postText.text = String(indexPath.row)
let data = postData[indexPath.row]

cell.postText.text = data as? String
return cell
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

I would like for the Firebase data to load in time for the array to be populated with said data which can then be used to populate my UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several answers here that contain good information. The real root of the issue is this:

```
var postData : [Any]!
```

So when the postData array is accessed before the array has data, it's nil and it crashes because you're attempting to get a .count property from a nil - that doesn't work.

```
return self.postData.count
```

Do this

```
var postData = [Post]()
```

That will instantiate the postData array with a count of 0.

Also note that from then on when func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection is called, it will return 0 because the array exists (it's not nil) with zero elements

You can feel free to use viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear, as in your question, to populate your tableView as long as once your dataSource is populated, you call tableView.reloadData as noted in the other answers.

```
    for post in posts! {
        self.postData.append(post)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Note that in your question, the same data is essentially being stored in several class vars which is probably unneeded so you may be able to remove currentPost and postDictionary. Also, be careful working with Dictionaries; remember they are unordered so if you read in some posts and put them in a Dictionary, they will loose their ordering.

I threw this together to get you going the right direction:

```
class PostClass {
    var postKey = ""
    var post = ""
    init(withKey: String, andPost: String) {
        self.postKey = withKey
        self.post = andPost
    }
}

var postsArray = [PostClass]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let postsRef = self.ref.child("posts")
    postsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allPosts = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for postSnap in allPosts {
            let postKey = postSnap.key
            let post = postSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "post").value as! String
            let aPost = PostClass(withKey: postKey, andPost: post)
            self.postsArray.append(aPost)
        }
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
        // a test to print the post objects
        for post in self.postsArray {
           let key = post.postKey
           let postText = post.post
           print(key, postText)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Everything worked but for some reason as I try to print what's in the array, it prints "cheerup_ios.Cheerup" three times. I named the class Cheerup in a separate file, was that wrong to do?

Comment: @danner.tech That sounds correct - if you store class objects in the array and then print them, it will print that object. If you wand to print a property of the object, it would be (in my example) print post.postKey. I'll add a little example into my answer. Oh - if the answer helps you, please accept it so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

For the very reason that network requests are done asynchronously, you should NEVER assume you have your data when presenting the table view. In fact, your table view will load much faster than most network requests (hence the crashes).

My suggestion is that you should always avoid force unwrapping your variables (i.e. using "!") In fact, since you're relatively new to iOS, I would avoid using "!" like it's the Black Plague.

change your variables to this:

```
var postDictionary : NSDictionary?
var currentPost: String?
var postData: [Any] = []
```

Doing this will force you to safely unwrap your variables. (i.e. check if it's nil)

Then make sure to reload your table view when you get your results.

#### More things you should do

I would take this one step further: I would avoid using `Any` and `NSDictionary` like the plague as well

You can of course keep using `NSDictionary` and `Any` variables, but you will have to endlessly keep casting them. And eventually, you won't even know what's going on in your code if you keep doing this.

change your posts to this:

```
var posts: [Post] = []
```

And use one of the following to convert your raw dictionaries into Post objects:
1. [Codable](https://medium.com/swift-india/use-of-codable-with-jsonencoder-and-jsondecoder-in-swift-4-71c3637a6c65)
2. [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper)
3. [MapCodableKit](https://github.com/cuba/MapCodableKit) (this is my framework which I personally prefer)

And then do this (using `MapCodableKit` example):

```
dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any?] else { return }
  guard let json = value["posts"] as? [String: Any?] else { return }
  self.posts = Posts(json: json)
  self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```